# Concrete5 Force SSL on system pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, concrete5

I am using the Force SSL plugin and need to make my login page have SSL. I do not want other pages to have SSL. Where do I enable this for the force SSL plugin?

I've also tried to program the following into the login template, but it results in a redirect loop even though I also put define('REDIRECT_TO_BASE_URL', false) in /config/site.php:

```
$redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location:$redirect");
```

I also tried to put the following in .htaccess but it resulted in page not found:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$https://www.peacefulschools.com/login/$1 [R,L]
```

My current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^peacefulschools\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.peacefulschools\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/peacefulschools\.com\/" [R=301,L]


# Use PHP54 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php

# -- concrete5 urls start --
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# -- concrete5 urls end --
```

How do I get https in the URL for the login page only whether utilizing the plugin or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a plugin or via php, you should be able to do this in your htaccess. See if that works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.peacefulschools.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^peacefulschools\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.peacefulschools\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.peacefulschools.com/ [R=301,L]


# Use PHP54 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php

# -- concrete5 urls start --
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# -- concrete5 urls end --
```

Comment: It's still not displaying it but I think it's because the other stuff I have in .htaccess. I'll add it to my question. What do you think?

Comment: Try this updated htaccess and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It's still not working for me :( if I type in peacefulschools.com/login it rewrites to http://www.peacefulschools.com/index.php/login/. I tried to see what would happen if I removed all of the rewrite conditions between the "concrete5 urls start" comments.. .and it then DOES redirect to https://peacefulschools.com/login but then has a bluehost page not found error. ideas?

Comment: BTW I still have the plugin installed because it works easily to redirect to https on our ecommerce pages

Comment: You're getting page not found because it looks like your URL is supposed to be `https://www.peachfulschools.com/index.php/login` try adding in the `index.php` before login in the redirect rule.

Comment: Like "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.peacefulschools.com/index.php/$1 [R=301,L]" ? Because that's not working either..

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.peacefulschools.com/index.php/login [R=301,L]` keep the other stuff above it.

Comment: Nope goes to h t t p://www.peacefulschools.com/index.php/login/ ... blah

Comment: Ok just remove everything in the contrete part and see what happens. But I suspect it's the setup and the plugin that removing the https